# Check the onEdit range on multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to create a script that, upon editing, can search both of my sheets at those same coordinates to check if the values match. Right now all I have been able to come up with is this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  if(col>1&&col<12){  
    if(row>1&&row<12){
      //function to search both sheets for matching values
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to successfully call a function where that comment is, but I don't know how to use the range variable to find the data on both sheets. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: OnEdit is called anytime you edit any cell in any sheet. You can use a conditional return if you want to avoid performing a process on certain sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the coordinates of the active cell, the following code should be sufficient.  I stored a test for cell value equivalency in the variable  `isCellEqual`.  You will just need to replace Sheet1 and Sheet2 with your sheet names.

```js
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  if(col>1&&col<12){  
    if(row>1&&row<12){
      var sheet1Cell=getCellValue('Sheet1',row,col);
      var sheet2Cell=getCellValue('Sheet2',row,col);
      var isCellEqual=sheet1Cell===sheet2Cell;
    }
  }
}

function getCellValue(sheetName,row,col){
 return SpreadsheetApp
    .getActive()
    .getSheetByName(sheetName)
    .getRange(row,col)
    .getValue();

}
```

Comment: I've tweaked some of your code to work with my script and I've almost got it ready except for one issue, I need to change the column numbers on the other sheet. IE: if someone changes something in the range on sheet one, the script needs to check that same range, but 11 columns over. Is there any way that I can get something like this? That could dynamically change which sheet is active is which is inactive?

`var Player1Cell=getCellValue(/* ACTIVE SHEET */,row,col);
var Player2Cell=getCellValue(/* INACTIVE SHEET */,row,col+11);`

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. All I needed to do was to check with an IF statement if the active sheet was a specific sheet (in my case 'Player 1') and then return the opposite and append an else to return the other sheet name.

`function check(){
  var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  var Active = sheetName;
  var InActive = inactive();
  Logger.log(Active);
  Logger.log(InActive);
}

function inactive(){
  if(sheetName=='Player 1'){
    return 'Player 2';
  }else{
    return 'Player 1';
  }
}`